# Using microsoft internet backgammon DLL

Tags: .net

are we enable to use Microsoft backgammon dll in our application?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939626%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx
for example Bckg.dll is game logix.
can we use it in out application?

Comment: Generally Microsoft isn't in the habit of providing an API and documentation in MSDN for products they don't want you to be able to use. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: please add as an answer and accept it, that way others here can see the result of this Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bckg.dll is not a COM component, it doesn't have a type library.  All you can eke out of it is the names of the exported functions.  Dumpbin.exe /exports shows this:

```
      1    0 000031BD ZoneClientExit
      2    1 00003242 ZoneClientGameAddKibitzer
      3    2 00003236 ZoneClientGameDelete
      4    3 000031DC ZoneClientGameNew
      5    4 00003274 ZoneClientGameProcessMessage
      6    5 0000325C ZoneClientGameRemoveKibitzer
      7    6 000031CD ZoneClientInternalName
      8    7 0000317E ZoneClientMain
      9    8 0000D0DD ZoneClientMessageHandler
     10    9 000031C2 ZoneClientName
     11    A 000031D6 ZoneClientVersion
     12    B 00003163 ZoneGameDllDelete
     13    C 0000310A ZoneGameDllInit
```

RemoveKibitzer sounds *very* interesting.  Anyhoo, you can't reverse-engineer the arguments of these functions from the dump.  MessageHandler and ProcessMessage would typically be your ultimate nemesis with just no way to figure out exactly *what* kind of messages are processed and handled.  This is a no-go.

Public service message for anyone interested in running the superior XP version on Vista or Win7: after copying the c:\program files\msn gaming zone\windows folder, run zClientm /regserver at the command prompt to get it installed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Microsoft isn't in the habit of providing an API and documentation in MSDN for products they don't want you to be able to use.

Comment: Isn't this @David Stratton's response?

Comment: yes i add his comment as my answer,
read third comment of my question.